# Округление числа в PHP

Tags: php

Есть плагин, который выводит цену в формате: базовая цена - %скидки = цена со скидкой. Очень часто цена выводится с копейками, т.е. 254.04, 340.98, 5401.69. Как округлить целую часть, убрать копейки? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
elseif (!empty($page_data['page_price_discount']) AND $page_data['page_price_discount']>0 AND empty($page_data['page_price_BYR_discount']))
{
    $temp_array['PRICE_BYR_DISCOUNT']
        = round($page_data['page_price_BYR'] - ($page_data['page_price_BYR'] * $page_data['page_price_discount'] / 100), 2);
}
elseif (!empty($page_data['page_price_discount']) AND !empty($page_data['page_price_BYR_discount']))
{
    switch ($cfg['plugin']['currency']['discount'])
    {
        case 'percent':
            $temp_array['PRICE_BYR_DISCOUNT']
                = round($page_data['page_price_BYR'] - ($page_data['page_price_BYR'] * $page_data['page_price_discount']
                    / 100), 2);
            break;
        case 'price':
            $temp_array['PRICE_DISCOUNT']
                = 100 - round($page_data['page_price_BYR_discount'] / $page_data['page_price_BYR'] * 100, 0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     case 'percent':
>         $temp_array['PRICE_BYR_DISCOUNT']
>             = round($page_data['page_price_BYR'] - ($page_data['page_price_BYR'] * $page_data['page_price_discount']
>                 / 100), 2);
>         break;
> ```

Видите этот участок кода? Условие "percent" он выводит Вам решение с копейками.
И в этом участке код тоже самое:

> ```
>  $temp_array['PRICE_BYR_DISCOUNT']
>     = round($page_data['page_price_BYR'] - ($page_data['page_price_BYR'] * $page_data['page_price_discount'] / 100), 2);
> ```

Потому что round() задан с аргументом вывода десятичных.

> ```
>   , 2);
> ```

Замените эту двойку на ноль, и десятичные пропадут.
Результат замены:

```
elseif (!empty($page_data['page_price_discount']) AND $page_data['page_price_discount']>0 AND empty($page_data['page_price_BYR_discount']))
{
    $temp_array['PRICE_BYR_DISCOUNT']
        = round($page_data['page_price_BYR'] - ($page_data['page_price_BYR'] * $page_data['page_price_discount'] / 100), 0);
}
elseif (!empty($page_data['page_price_discount']) AND !empty($page_data['page_price_BYR_discount']))
{
    switch ($cfg['plugin']['currency']['discount'])
    {
        case 'percent':
            $temp_array['PRICE_BYR_DISCOUNT']
                = round($page_data['page_price_BYR'] - ($page_data['page_price_BYR'] * $page_data['page_price_discount']
                    / 100), 0);
            break;
        case 'price':
            $temp_array['PRICE_DISCOUNT']
                = 100 - round($page_data['page_price_BYR_discount'] / $page_data['page_price_BYR'] * 100, 0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

> [**Подробное описание функции round() можно изучить по этой ссылке.**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php)

Творческих успехов Вам.

Comment: @Persol Не за что :)

Answer (score 0):

`echo floor(340.98);`

Результат: `340`

Answer (score 0):

Я туповат. Решение простейшее
Подставил round перед ($page_data['page_price_BYR'] * $page_data['page_price_discount'] / 100)

```
{
    $temp_array['PRICE_BYR_DISCOUNT']
        = round($page_data['page_price_BYR'] - round($page_data['page_price_BYR'] * $page_data['page_price_discount'] / 100), 2);
}
```

Comment: Зачем? Не проще упростить аргумент функции!?